# WooCommerce Product Publish Date & Author Displayed - How To Remove/Hide?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am setting up a website through Wordpress using Better Health Theme by Canyon Themes and WooCommerce plugin for the online shop.
Above the product it displays a publish date and the author, any idea how to remove this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:none;` property in css to hide date & author.

Example:

```
.theclassname {
display: none;
```

}

Comment: Does not affect the author showing up in google searches!